# C input problems

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm trying to create a simple program in C. Here is kinda what I have so far for the basics

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char input[256];
  while(1)
  {
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    if(strcmp(input, "help") == 0)
      printf("HELP STUFF HERE\n");
    else if(strcmp(input, "1") == 0)
      printf("2\n");
    else if(strcmp(input, "test 1") == 0)
      printf("Test 1\n");
    else if(strcmp(input, "test 2") == 0)
      printf("Test 2\n");
    else
      printf("Error");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm having some problems though. First of all I can't use spaces. If I try test 1, I get the output of Error. Second problem I'm having is when it outputs Error, it prints it onto the user input prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is to change `"%s"` in `scanf` to `"%[^\n]"`, which reads all characters other than a newline.

The better answer is to change it to `"%255[^\n]"`, which does the same but includes bounds checking.

The best answer is to use `fgets`, which doesn't have funky issues with what exactly it will read, or make it difficult to do proper bounds checking.

Comment: This is the first time I ever see such scanf format specifier. It looks like a regex. Is this even standard?

Comment: Hm I've tried the first two suggestions you gave me and when I type 1 it prints 2 over and over etc. I'll look into fgets more.

Comment: @AustinM - Yes, it is. (I was skeptical too when I first heard it.)

Comment: @AustinM - That's part of `scanf`'s annoyances. I think `" %255[^\n]"` would solve that issue, but not very precisely (it would eat up whitespace before the text starts). `fgets` is still the best solution IMHO.

Comment: I'm having problems with fgets() now. If I use gets() it works fine. But if I use fgets(input, 256, stdin); it prints ERROR each time.

Comment: @AustinM - `fgets` doesn't strip the newlines from the data it returns. You either have to do that yourself or add newlines to all the test strings.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you write `scanf('%s')`, on input `test 1` the `%s` only scans up to the first space and the input your program receives is actually only `test`.

A useful thing to do in terms of debugging would be to do a

```
printf("Error: %s", input)
```

So you can see what `scanf` is getting you.

If you just want whole lines of input, `fgets()` is better to use.

Comment: Never ever use gets, only use fgets.